# Install Windows 8 without a Product Key

Tags: windows-8, product-key

Windows 8 setup asks for the product key at the beginning of the setup without letting you install it.

I got the Windows 8 ISO from MSDN but I didn't get enough keys to install it on all my 7 computers. Also, my MSDN subscription level doesn't allow me to get the VL product key to Windows 8 Enterprise.

Is there any way I can install Windows 8 for a limited time period like we used to do for Windows 7 ?

Comment: The real trick is to call MS support and tell them that your Windows isn't activating. Works everytime.

Comment: @Mikhail, I don’t see how; they will ask you to re-enter your key, and when you say you don’t have one…

Comment: similar answer for Windows 10: https://superuser.com/a/1120631/35525

Answer (score 53, accepted):

1. [Create a bootable USB flash drive to install Windows 8](http://www.techrepublic.com/photos/create-a-bootable-usb-flash-drive-for-windows-8-installation/6386574).
2. Navigate to `<FlashDrive>:\Sources\`
3. Save a file called `ei.cfg` in that folder with the following text:

   ```
   [EditionID]
   Core
   [Channel]
   Retail
   [VL]
   0
   ```

If you want to install the Pro edition, replace `Core` with `Professional`. If you want the setup to ask which edition you want install without entering the product key, leave the `[EditionID]` blank.

You can also set `[VL]` (Volume Licensing) to 1 (for true) and `[Channel]` to `OEM`/`Retail`

Now install as normal and the Windows 8 setup won't ask for the product key. This will work for every copy of Windows 8 that you can get from anywhere.

Also, **if you ever to want to enter the product key, you can do so from the Windows Activation window** or using the `slui 3` command.

Comment: Will I be able to enter the key later to make it a full version?

Comment: @silent_cookie yes, Windows will prompt you to enter a Windows key every time you start up.

Comment: This answer does not explain how to download the ISO.

Comment: @StevenPenny Do you think its difficult to do?

Comment: I tried this but the installation prompted me with "The product key entered does not match any of the Windows images available for installation. Enter a different product key."

Comment: it worked, but I had to use `[Edition ID]` with a space

Answer (score 18):

The answer of User is correct, but you can also leave EditionID in ei.cfg blank:

```
[EditionID]

[Channel]
OEM
[VL]
0
```

Now Windows 7 and 8 Setup will let you install without Product Key, **and also lets you choose the Edition you want to install**. You don't need to edit ei.cfg every time.

Comment: There was just an issue when mixing x86 and amd64 images in one wim (works fine with Win7, but Win8 Setup explains this image would not be compatible with your hardware). Didn't try latest Win8.x Setups, but probably you have to add first the amd64 images and then the x86 to the wim file.

Comment: This is the one that worked for me, installing from the iso downloaded from microsoft.

Answer (score 10):

Quickest option (no need to modify and burn a DVD or create an install flash drive) is to use a generic key. They are keys that can't be used for activation but only to bypass that installer screen.

[Here](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/47480-windows-8-1-generic-keys?s=25a60467738692e708ab7ecb4d271e43&p=794029&viewfull=1#post794029) is a list of generic keys. If the link is dead just Google `windows 8.1 generic key`.

edit: found a new link https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-81-product-activation-with-windows-8/40997a3b-a901-4abf-939a-afb11e296c10

Answer (score -1):

windows 8 is free for 90 days.There should be a skip option at the bottom of the screen where it asks for the product key.clicking this you can install the 90 days evaluation copy

HTH

Comment: Indeed! I have voted up this answer. Microsoft did release a 90 day evaluation version of Windows 8 Enterprise. The OP was looking for a way to "install Windows 8 for a limited time period". A 90 day evaluation period... well, I don't know about you guys but that seems like a pretty generous time limit. Well I am sorry guys if this does not give you a licensed copy of Windows 8 Enterprise for free... as in free bananas! Boo hoo!... But it does answer the question! At least one part of the question. It's a two-part question really: get rid of product key prompt + get a free ride on Windows 8.

Comment: Here is a post on Tech Republic about the 90 day trial version: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/get-the-free-90-day-evaluation-of-windows-8-enterprise/

Comment: As a matter of fact I have just finished installing Windows 8.1 (the new eight) Enterprise using the `en_windows_8_1_enterprise_x64_dvd_2971902` image. It did not prompt me for a key and I am running it in evaluation mode as I type. The same was not true for the slightly older `en_windows_8_1_x64_dvd_2707217` image. It kept prompting for a key. I do have a license and a key that works with it, but I just wanted the damn thing installed. I did try the trick originally posted by @metadings and it did work. But if you do have the Enterprise image, it's much easier and totally legit.

Comment: The difference between the two aforementioned images are discussed here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/660ee5af-247a-427d-87fe-d9f35a5e70cd/difference-between-enwindows81enterprisex64dvd2971902iso-released-1710-and?forum=w8itproinstall

Answer (score -1):

MSDN keys are multi-activation which is why they don't provide you with a bunch.

I have read that at some point they will cut you off but then all you need to do is just call them up and they very lenient about resetting the count.

Comment: Keys of `Retail` type also ?

Comment: I think only `MAK` type of keys support multi-activation.

Comment: I routinely install products from MSDN all the time (Windows 8, Windows 7 ect) and haven't had an issue with activation yet. Many years ago I had Bizspark and had like 20 keys - I assumed it was one activation per key. I called support after they limited the keys to 1 or 2 and they told me the keys are multi-activation and have activated a product many times using a single key.