# After activating Windows 10, do I need to connect to the Internet ever again?

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection, windows-activation

I have a computer which I can initially connect to the Internet for activation, but would like to use in an offline setting after that. I can't find whether my activation is valid forever, or if it needs renewal. The [activation FAQ](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12440/windows-10-activation) does not mention it. The only relevant thing I read [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/thepiratebay/comments/4fot7w/windows_10_keygen/d2aoaok/) is that illegal KMS activators for Windows 10 need to keep running in order to keep the system believing it's legally activated.

I have a valid license and have not / will not use such an activator, but this sparks the question: Is this because of something like Windows Update which connects to the Internet regularly, after which the system finds it's not genuine, does Windows 10 require an Internet connection regularly to keep checking its license or does such an 'activator' simply extend the trial/grace period over and over again (which would not apply to me)?

My specific Windows version is Education, in case that makes a difference.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/498628/how-long-is-the-windows-8-activation-period-if-i-do-not-connect-to-the-internet) sounds similar, but is about "... if I [never] connect to the Internet", whereas I can initially do that.

Comment: Worth pointing out you don't have to even connect to the internet to activate Windows, if you activate by phone, everything can be done offline.

Comment: @Ramhound True, but it's rather cumbersome for a system that I hope not to have to touch too often. If that were needed, I'd look for a different solution. Thanks for the tip, though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have activated using KMS, you do not need to periodically reconnect to the Internet to maintain Windows 10's activation. I think Microsoft's silence on this fact is simply due to there not being any such requirement.

Keep in mind that not connecting to the Internet means you won't get any security updates. This will leave your machine vulnerable to threats it may come into contact with, such as those transmitted by portable flash drives. For an interesting read on how offline computers can still be subject to attack see Wikipedia's article on the [Stuxnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuxnet?wprov=sfla1) worm.

Comment: I thought KMS was the activation system (it apparently stands for Key Management System). Is this not the default way to activate? My activation screen says it was activated using a digital license.

Comment: @Luc No, KMS is not the default way to activate. It's only available to organizations that have volume license agreements with Microsoft.

Comment: @Luc - A digital entitlement only applies to Windows 10.