# How I can check my Windows 8 Pro expiration date?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have installed Microsoft Windows 8 Pro.

I want to activate it. I have tried to buy Windows 8 Pro by using the "Buy a new key" option but it's not working.

So it looks like before I buy Windows it will be in trial. It is not showing me the date of the trial expiration.

Someone let me know how I can use it for 90 days (as a trial before I get it). How I can check the trial's expiration date?

This photo shows what happens when I run `slmgr.vbs -XPR` in the command prompt:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoJeh.png]

Comment: See [Is Windows Pro usable without activation?](http://superuser.com/q/498714/3774) question.

Comment: @user1769787 - You will have to use Windows 8 Enterprise 90 day, at the end of 90 days, you can format your system and install Windows 8 or Windows 8 Pro.

Answer (score 7):

**To check Trial Version Expire Date.** *( Only For Windows 8 DP CP RP )*

Open `winver` command via Run <kbd>Win Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>  or in MetroUI Startmenu.

[image: Reference Image showing Expire Date]

**To upgrade any Windows 7 / Windows 8 DP CP RP etc..**

[Upgrade Assistant](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=261871)

**Windows 8 RTM Evaluation for devs. [90 days](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx)**

Once the evaluation period expires, your desktop background will turn black, and your PC will shut down every hour to prevent you from using it.

Comment: -1: This does not show an expiry date on Windows Pro (not Preview).

Comment: DzinX, thanks for indicating error, i have added cautionary note that it is only for DP CP RP. I will update it with more details sooner.

Comment: @MayurPipaliya - There isn't an evaluation period for Windows 8 and Windows 8 RTM.  Only Windows 8 Enterprise has a 90 day trial WHICH CANNOT be upgrade to a full copy.

Comment: **DP=Developer Preview; CP=Consumer Preview; RP=Release Preview**

Answer (score 7):

with **winver**  command you will not see the expiration date, if your  windows is already activated (for instance you activate your system with 1 year key license). please run this command to see your system expiration date: **slmgr/xpr**

Comment: Displaying the verbose licensing with `slmgr /dlv` worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt and type this command:

```
Cscript Slmgr.vbs -dli
```

It willdisplay how much time left before you must activate.

Comment: oops, sorry I forget to put it on post. please check it.

Comment: I think you meant `slmgr /xpr`. "Expiration date for current license state". That's what it says if you run `cmd /c slmgr` from Run prompt. The switch `-dli` is to display license information. And `-dlv` is to display additional (v for verbose) license information.