# How long can I use Windows 10 without activation?

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

It would seem that there should be web resources to quickly find an answer to this question but I couldn't find any, so I'm trying my luck here.

I used the Win10 Media Creation Tool to download Win10 Pro ISO's and set up VM's I use for testing before deploying to bare metal. Once I deploy, I do so with a digital license or product key but it obviously doesn't make any sense activating while in the (temporary) VM.

Now I noticed that my VM still works, and it's been many weeks since I first used it. It's not activated, of course, but I can still log in and install software and so on.

Up until now, I always created a new VM installation from scratch when I needed to do testing. It would naturally save me some time if I could just install it once and then clone when I need a new environment (that will eventually be licensed). I thought that's not possible due to some time restraints so I didn't even try it.

Hence my questions:

- Is there an official "evaluation period" for Windows 10, and how long is it?
- How long can one use (from a technical perspective only) a not activated copy of Windows 10?
- Which limitations are there for a not activated copy and when do they step into effect? <strike>I was, for example, not able to confirm that personalization is not possible as seems to have been the case with a not-activated Windows 8.</strike>  (See comment on answer below.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long can one use a fresh Windows 10 install without product key?](http://superuser.com/questions/1024066/how-long-can-one-use-a-fresh-windows-10-install-without-product-key)

Comment: With regards to my second point, it's a duplicate. The other two aspects are not mentioned in the other question.

Comment: That is the problem asking multiple questions in one post here so I default to the title of the question. William Seems to have answered them anyway.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> Is there an official "evaluation period" for Windows 10, and how long is it?

There isn't really a proper evaluation period by default on a standard copy, especially since it is free if you have a regular copy and the vast majority of machines compatible are eligible. So, you either have a proper legal copy that is not activated, or, you can download a 90 day trial of Windows Enterprise direct from Microsoft.

> How long can one use (from a technical perspective only) a not activated copy of Windows 10?

There is no limitation.

> Which limitations are there for a not activated copy and when do they step into effect? I was, for example, not able to confirm that personalization is not possible as seems to have been the case with a not-activated Windows 8.

You get a watermark in the bottom right hand corner of the screen and you can't utilise Microsoft account services such as syncing settings between devices. Other than that, it pretty much works as expected.

**My Experience:**

Since I changed my motherboard a while ago, I have had an "unlicensed" copy which I haven't been able to reactive. I have to say, other than the watermark, I wouldn't really know that this was the case.

Comment: Hi William, thanks for your reply. I was specifically referring to the Win10 ISO you get with the Media Creation Tool, not the Enterprise demo. Since I'm using it in a VM, I am generally not eligible. Also, I have no watermark in the bottom right hand corner (or anywhere else for that matter) even though my copy is clearly not activated. So, I wonder if it's just a matter of time before that watermark shows or if there is another difference at play here.

Comment: @vic yes its just a matter of time. I believe a month is the time period before a non-activated copy will show the watermark. But I have no proof to back it up, only first-hand experience.

Comment: OK, I can confirm that now I get the watermark, too. And it is *no longer possible* to personalize the screen. I didn't check for other limitations but I assume it's, at least, the same as it was for Windows 8.

Comment: If you activated Windows 10 on the host ever your virtual machine more then likely is activated

Comment: Afaik if you join the windows insider program and the fast ring these 90 days are renewed with every build you get. As fast ring builds are more frequent than only every 90 days this helps you to stay activated at all times. The downside is that you have to deal with (a lot?) less stable builds.

Comment: You can't seem to change your desktop wallpaper via personalize without activating either. Though right clicking on an image to make it a background image works.

Comment: @Syberdoor That's interesting. Actually you also get a watermark on the bottom right corner of the screen saying that it's an "evaluation copy" for all insider preview builds. But since for now Insider Preview is still officially required for the Linux Subsystem, it's very natural to have Insider Preview builds installed anyways.

Comment: @Syberdoor However, that doesn't seem to actually work, since the personalization options are still disabled. It seems that using Insider Preview and activating the Windows are two separate matters. Even if you've installed the Insider Preview, as long as the Windows is not activated, everything remains the same.

Comment: @xji - Insider Preview builds are absolutely not required for Windows Linux Subsystem (WSL).

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah I don't think now it's the case any longer. More than half a year has passed! It has to get out of beta at some point. That's why I explicitly said "for now" in the original comment.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [retail license agreement](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm), section 5:

> "You are authorized to use this software only if you are properly licensed and the software has been properly activated with a genuine product key or by other authorized method."

So if the software has never been properly activated, you are not authorized to use it, and by my reading, you can't use it under this license. I'm going to assume that they mean "has been properly activated" to apply to a particular installation, and not Windows 10 as a software product, because surely someone has activated Windows 10 ever. It might apply per copy instead, though, so if you activate on one device and then move your license to a new device, you may not need to activate the new device.

So, in my non-lawyerly legal opinion, the official evaluation period is length 0, and you are committing copyright infringement the moment you boot an un-activated Windows 10.

Interestingly, I couldn't find an exception that allows you to use Windows 10 to run your computer long enough to enter your product key and activate it. Any use of an unactivated copy, including installing and activating it, is unauthorized. So pretty much everyone seems to have violated the license terms.

Comment: @Ramhound Can you point to any language in the license agreement, or anything else published by Microsoft, to support a nonzero-length evaluation period?

Obviously the fact that the license agreement doesn't grand you a license to use Windows to activate Windows is just faulty drafting and not something Microsoft expects to be able to enforce. But they clearly prohibit just using an unactivated copy of Windows forever, even if there's no technical measures in the software to enforce this.

Comment: Oh, maybe there's a different license document for Enterprise; I should have specified that I was looking at the retail license agreement.

Comment: It's actually a valid train of thought. The question clearly isn't about trial licenses but about a regular installation of Windows 10 that was not installed using a proper license and that is not activated. Reading the excerpt you provided, I'd agree that the evaluation period for that type of product really is 0. Any objection to the contrary should be accompanied by respective sources. Having said that, I do believe that William already answered the same when writing "There isn't really a proper evaluation period by default on a standard copy".

Comment: "you are committing copyright infringement the moment you boot an un-activated Windows 10" - This would make it impossible to install a legally obtained copy of Windows. Normally you must boot it first in order to activate it. Violating the EULA also does not necessarily mean you are committing copyright infringement.

Comment: (Yes, the 'committing copyright infringement...' above is totally incorrect.)  Here's my recent experience and an educated guess on how it works:  Three days ago, I wiped my SSD and installed Windows-10 Home on a 4 or 5 year-old laptop that had been running Windows-10:  It hasn't YET started showing water-mark infoo, but I expect it soon will.  [One other time I did this, I ended up calling Microsoft support, and, based upon information they had at their end, they happily (re-) activated my newly-installed Win-10 Home for me.]

Comment: Also: (The product-key DOES get put originally into the BIOS area on newer PCs, rather than get affixed on a label as it did in the 'old days'. But I had neglected to learn how to get at it in the BIOS, and I'm not sure it would have worked, had I tried using that.)  Anyway, as I said above, Microsoft activated it, using a product-key that they supplied.