# Install Windows 10 Home before paying for it

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, emulator

I would like to run Windows 10 on my Mac using VirtualBox, purely just for testing any websites that I build.

I sometimes have trouble getting these things to work (my Mac is quite old which occasionally causes problems with things like this), and so I'm not keen on paying £120 on something when I don't know for sure that I'll be able to run it.

I noticed there is a 90 day trial of Enterprise, but is this not the case with the Home edition?

If not, is it at least possible to install it first somehow, and then pay when you first turn it on?

Comment: You don't need a license key to install Windows 10, any version. It will just bug you about not being activated.

Comment: @SamForbis almost correct. Enterprise editions don't follow this logic. And of course it limits you in a few things such as being able to change the background color and color scheme.

Comment: That's right, I meant to say "consumer" version. My bad!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long can I use Windows 10 without activation?](https://superuser.com/questions/1024274/how-long-can-i-use-windows-10-without-activation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the home and pro editions of Windows 10, the testing period is 30 days before it will say that it could not activate.

When windows 10 home or pro is not activated, you can still use it, but certain personalization options stop working.

Windows Updates continue to work, and the OS will remain to work indefinitely, you just keep having the watermark and you can't do things like changing the background. So you can test it indefinitely until you install a license and activate the OS.