# What is the activation status of Windows 10 pre-installed on a PC that is never connected to the Internet?

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

A description of a particular PC model says that the computer has Windows 10 Pro on it. Does this imply that Windows is *already activated*? I am asking because I have read that Windows 10 requires Internet connection for activation. For example, I have read various answers here:

[www.quora.com | What is pre-installed Windows 10?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-pre-installed-Windows-10-What-does-it-mean-What-about-the-licence-of-Windows-Should-I-purchase-another-licence-key-or-is-the-pre-installed-version-activated-Does-pre-installed-Windows-have-regular-updates)

Some of them say that Windows is activated, some say that the Internet will be needed for activation.

What I have found is this:

> The default product key is also known as the OEM master key, the OEM manufacturing key, the OEM setup key, or the OEM SLP key.
> The default product key is edition-specific and cannot activate Windows. Instead, it instructs Windows to search for the injected OA 3.0 product key in the firmware.

(Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/oa3-staging-master-image-w-default-key)

And this:

> The Windows activation system is designed to use the product key that's injected into the firmware of the computer during manufacturing. It automatically activates the device when the device first comes online.

(Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/validate-oem-activation-key)

And this:

> OEM versions of Windows 10 are identical to Full License Retail versions except for the following:
>
> OEM versions require an active internet connection that can reach the Microsoft network for product activation.
> If your organization operates on a closed network, please contact your account team to discuss the benefits of a Volume Licensing (VLA) solution from Dell.

(Source: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000126935/requirements-for-dell-windows-10-activation?lwp=rt)

And this:

> All HP computers and tablets shipped with Windows 10 will activate automatically when connected to the internet.
> [...]
> Activating using a Digital Product Key or OEM Activation 3.0 (OA3): Windows 10 is activated via the internet by validating a Digital Product Key (DPK) that was included in the BIOS.
> [...]
> If a system has a Digital Product Key that was injected into the system BIOS during the manufacturing process, Windows 10 will use that key to activate Windows 10 on that specific system. Activation is automatic when connected to the internet. All HP systems sold with Windows 10 will include a Digital Product Key in the BIOS.

(Source: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04640037)

And this page contains two seemingly contradictory statements:

> If your ASUS computer is with the built-in Windows operating system when you purchased it, a digital license had been injected into the ASUS motherboard of your product, and Windows will be automatically activated after the computer connects to the internet.
> [...]
> For ASUS computer built-in Windows system, its Window has been activated.

(Source: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1015074/#Win10)

I cannot understand what it means. Windows "will be automatically activated" or "has been activated"?

So my question is: if this PC will *never* be connected to the Internet and an end-user will not perform *any* actions to activate Windows (such as using the phone for activation, running a program etc.), will the pre-installed Windows 10 remain unactivated? Or maybe the answer depends on the model of a PC (i.e. some models are sold with pre-activated Windows, yet some models are sold with the assumption that the user will need to connect a PC to the Internet to activate the OS)?

**UPDATE**

I have found the following information:

> Most OEM-provided devices designed to run Windows 8 or later will have a firmware-embedded key.

(Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/deploy-enterprise-licenses)

> Firmware-embedded – never needs to be on internet connection, it can be in a deferred activation state and never watermark
> [...]
> Firmware-embedded activation key is the Windows OEM license (Digital Product Key (DPK) also known as Digital License) which comes embedded in the device firmware and reflects the version that the device was purchased with (Home or Pro).

(Source: https://moderneuc.com/windows-activation-evolution/)

But I cannot seem to find a comprehensive source describing what the "Deferred activation" state is. Is it automatically extended to last until a PC goes online? The only reliable source mentioning this state is the HP document (linked above). All other mentions of this state that I have found are in the context of Windows IoT/Embedded, which is not relevant for my question. For example, I have found the following information:

> Do you know if deferred activation has some limitations, such as less access to windows settings, etc.?
>
> Personalization settings will be blocked, but you can get around those with group policies and registry settings.

(Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/492619/windows-10-iot-enterprise-offline-activation.html)

This may imply that the "Deferred activation" state is *not* a complete simulation of the "Activated" state, from the functionality point of view...

Comment: "seemingly contradictory statements": The claim "For ASUS computer built-in Windows system, its Window has been activated." is in the context of the "Windows hasn't been activated", the message on screen. I understand this as: You should never see "Windows hasn't been activated" on an ASUS Computer except for the cases listed below.

Answer (score 5):

The [other](https://superuser.com/a/1724127/1008469) answer says:

> No legally preinstalled Windows comes pre-activated.

While this statement is true regarding the fact that full windows activation requires an online connection to Microsoft servers for OEM preinstalled Windows and Retail Windows, it is also misleading because OEM preinstalled Windows installations will not ship non-activated either, they will ship in what is now called the the state of **Deferred Activation**.
What is usually understood as an [activated Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Product_Activation) is a fully functional installation without any time limit, watermarks on the desktop or messages prompting for activation.
This [answer details limitations of non-activated Windows with screenshots](https://superuser.com/a/498715/1008469) for 8 but is applicable to 10 as well.

Usually all OEM installations use [SLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Locked_Pre-installation) with a generic product key while retail Windows uses individual product keys entered during Setup.

The latest incarnation of SLP is version 3.0 and many details regarding the activation have changed with the introduction of Windows 8.
Prior to version 3 the SLP method was called the OEM activation method because it activated with firmware information alone, without internet or phone activation needed. OEM activation was an offline process, while for retail Windows installations using individual product keys the online or phone activation was mandatory to reach the fully functional state. The information in the firmware was a SLIC ACPI table with generic non individual information. For Windows to activate using the generic product key and the generic firmware information an OEM certificate matching the hardware SLIC had to be installed in Windows. This means the OEM activation was usually only available with the pre-installed image of Windows on the computer and with the OEM supplied factory recovery solution because a freshly installed Windows from Microsoft supplied ISOs would not contain the certificate.

But since Windows 8 with SLP 3.0 the whole process is different because every firmware has a unique licence key embedded in a MSDM ACPI table.

Form a Windows `cmd` you can display the firmware embedded product key with this command:

```
wmic path SoftwareLicensingService get OA3xOriginalProductKey
```

It looks like a normal product key but it will not work if entered directly into setup or the change product key screen because it is bound to the motherboard of the particular OEM PC.

The correct way to make Windows use this embedded product key is to enter one of the generic product keys. The list of the generic or default OEM product keys in the wikipedia article above is not exhaustive, the [full list of Windows 10 keys released by Microsoft is here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/95922-generic-product-keys-install-windows-10-editions.html), they are [documented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/oa3-staging-master-image-w-default-key) as follows:

> The default product key is edition-specific and cannot activate Windows. Instead, it instructs Windows to search for the injected OA 3.0 product key in the firmware.

Prior to [OA 3.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/oem-activation-3) the activation of the OS and the validation of the license were presented to the end user as two separate processes. The online validation was called [genuine advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Genuine_Advantage). This validation of the license was only necessary to receive automatic updates via the internet.
The mention of *validation* as the final step can still be found in the current documentation liked above:

> Windows Activation and Validation Services (Windows AVS)
> A Microsoft web service that validates the Windows operating system and finishes the activation process after an end user completes the out-of-box experience (OOBE) process.

It's save to assume that all standard PCs and Laptops sold from bigger manufacturers use firmware embedded activation and according to the information you provided in the question were not connected to the internet before. On the other hand it could be that you will get a System Builder Version of Windows (equivalent to a retail version) for a custom build computer with non-OEM hardware from a smaller manufacturer with an individual product key, but most probably it would be online activated by the manufacturer during the custom build process.

Documentation on what exactly the **Deferred Activation** means is scarce, some sources on the internet claim, that the 'Windows activation' screen under 'Settings - Update & Security' will show

> Connect to the internet to activate Windows

when in the state of deferred activation.

The [HP service document](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04640037) is very specific about the fact that an OEM activated device that never activated online can be used without limitations:

> If the system cannot be connected to the internet and activated, the system is in the 'Deferred Activation' state. Windows 10 can be used normally while in 'Deferred Activation'. No message is displayed on the desktop indicating that Windows is not activated. A system with a valid DPK or Product Key will activate automatically when connected to the internet.

So what exactly is the the state of **Deferred Activation**?
It seems to be the state of a freshly installed Windows 10 that was never connected to the internet.

The license status of a non-activated Windows is called "Notification" by `slmgr /dli` or "Windows is in Notification mode" by `slmgr /xpr`.
The license status of an activated Windows is "Licensed" and "The machine is permanently activated"

A clean installation from a Media Creation Tool Windows 10 21H2 ISO on offline OEM hardware containing a MSDM table using an empty hard disk clicking "I don't have a key" in Setup installs the generic "Retail" or "RTM Generic Key (retail)" key and Windows is in "Notification" mode.
For Home Edition this is equivalent to:

```
slmgr /ipk YTMG3-N6DKC-DKB77-7M9GH-8HVX7
slmgr /dlv
```

[image: offline - "RTM Generic Key (retail)" - "Windows is in Notification mode"]

---

Changing to "OEM:DM" or "Generic product key for manufacturers" key and Windows is in "Notification" mode.
For Home Edition changing the key can be achieved by:

```
slmgr /ipk 37GNV-YCQVD-38XP9-T848R-FC2HD
slmgr /dlv
```

[image: offline - "Generic product key for manufacturers" - "Windows is in Notification mode"]

---

Changing to "OEM:NONSLP" or "Generic product key for system builders" key and Windows is in "Notification" mode.
For Home Edition changing the key can be achieved by:

```
slmgr /ipk 46J3N-RY6B3-BJFDY-VBFT9-V22HG
slmgr /dlv
```

[image: offline - "Generic product key for system builders" - "Windows is in Notification mode"]

---

The 'Windows activation' screen under 'Settings - Update & Security' shows in all cases:

> Unable to reach Windows activation servers

[image: "Unable to reach Windows activation servers"]

---

But none of the limitations are there. The

> Windows is not activated

message only appears after the key is removed.
Removing the key can be achieved by:

```
slmgr /upk
```

[image: no valid key - "Windows is not activated"]

Then functional limitations like the disabled personalisation appear:

[image: "You need to activate Windows before you can personalize your PC"]

After you add one of the generic keys and still be offline it will revert back to fully functional like above.

Once you connect to the internet it will quickly activate with a digital license and it doesn't matter which one of the three generic keys is used.

Changing to "Retail" or "RTM Generic Key (retail)" key and Windows is in "Licensed" mode:

[image: online - "RTM Generic Key (retail)" - "Licensed" "The machine is permanently activated"]

---

Changing to "OEM:DM" or "Generic product key for manufacturers" key and Windows is in "Licensed" mode:

[image: online - "Generic product key for manufacturers" - "Licensed" "The machine is permanently activated"]

"OEM:DM" should be the real one for firmware embedded licenses.

---

Changing to "OEM:NONSLP" or "Generic product key for system builders" key and Windows is in "Licensed" mode:

[image: online - "Generic product key for system builders" - "Licensed" "The machine is permanently activated"]

---

If you stay offline after that quick online activation it will always revert back to "Licensed" mode after you remove the key or change the key.

Another experiment in an offline VM revealed that setting the system clock forward several months never actually showed the "Windows is not activated" message and personalisation continued to be available. This is consistent with the observation that there is no mention of a grace period in the screenshots of the `slmgr /dlv` output above compared with the screenshots in the linked answer about Windows 8 activation messages and limitations. Manually installing the monthly [cumulative updates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/windows-10-update-history-857b8ccb-71e4-49e5-b3f6-7073197d98fb) works without issues, so the activation or validation is not necessary for that either. Note the "Installed On" date in the following screenshot is about three months in the future from the time of writing.

[image: Successful manual installation of Windows updates in an offline environment]

Windows 10 seems to be very graceful in an offline environment and so far it seems can be used without limitations with the generic keys for an unlimited time.

To conclude, the "Windows is not activated" mode with limitations and messages only appears after you go online and activation fails with the generic keys because your hardware does not contain a valid key for the particular edition of Windows in the firmware and you would be supposed to enter a valid and unique product key.

Comment: Suppose that a PC is with OEM-activated Windows 10 Pro. What will happen if an end-user performs a "clean install" of Windows 10 Pro from a FPP-licensed USB flash drive and this drive has an independent product key? (Such drives can be used to install Windows on a PC with no OS.) Will the OS remain OEM-activated, i.e. activated automatically offline (without Internet connection)? In this case, an individual product key will be not needed at all (for this PC)?

Comment: "This is also called the OEM activation method because it activates with firmware information alone, without internet or phone activation needed." — please, see the edited question. It seems that the Internet connection will be required, even with the OEM activation method...

Comment: @lyricallywicked Unless a different version of Windows is being installed that didn't come pre installed from an OEM, the OEM key stored in the BIOS/UEFI firmware will be used to activate _(it's common for Setup to not prompt for a key in this scenario)_, but if a different version of Windows is installed, a product key will be required to activate. Microsoft requires all OEMs to provide a CoA [Certificate of Authenticity] sticker somewhere on the PC, which contains a unique product key, as well as a unique serial code for issuing a new product key should the product key become unreadable.

Comment: @JW0914: "the OEM key stored in the BIOS/UEFI firmware will be used to activate" — is the Internet connection required for this activation?

Comment: @lyricallywicked An internet connection is always required, as Windows auto-activates via Windows Update in >Win8; however, whether the customer ever sees that depends on how the OEM configured their [ZTI](https://superuser.com/a/1721319/529800) [Zero Touch Install] Task Sequence, as they can auto-activate via the Task Sequence in the `auditSystem` configuration pass.

Comment: @xenoson It's simply impractical for an OEM to not have an OEM key contract, as the alternative is cost prohibitive. Any OEM selling laptops/PCs/servers with Windows ≥8 preinstalled uses OEM activation, whereas resllers/refurbishers will use retail keys, however both must provide a Windows CoA sticker to the customer. OEM keys require an OEM contract with Microsoft and it's guaranteed any OEM selling laptops/PCs/servers with Windows ≥8 preinstalled is using OEM keys since OEMs were contractually mandated to support Secure Boot in order to be able to preinstall Windows 8 and future versions.

Comment: What I do not understand is who must go online to activate Windows in the case of SLP.. A seller or an end-user? Suppose that a person bought a PC with Windows 10 Pro "pre-installed", then carried it to a place where there will never be any connection to the Internet. Will Windows remain unactivated?

Comment: @lyricallywicked I directly answered that in my last reply - it depends upon how the OEM configured their ZTI _([ZTI example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9l5c.png), with the activation occuring in the next to last column within the `State Restore` section: `Windows Update (Pre-Application Install)`)_

Comment: @JW0914: Does `Windows Update (Pre-Application Install)` include (or imply) `Windows activation`?

Comment: @lyricallywicked Please see [prior comment:](https://superuser.com/questions/1724119/what-is-the-activation-status-of-windows-10-pre-installed-on-a-pc-that-is-never/1724127?noredirect=1#comment2663703_1724179) "_Windows auto-activates via Windows Update in >Win8_". This isn't exclusive and can be done in multiple ways within the ZTI Task Sequence, it's simply how I configured mine for my laptop _(e.g. a task could be added to activate via CLI during `auditSystem`, `auditUser`, `oobeSystem`, or at any point after OOBE prior to the Task Sequence completing)_.

Comment: @JW0914: So the answer to my question is "It depends upon how the OEM configured their ZTI. OEMs can pre-activate Windows via their ZTI."? But it naturally raises the next question: do they actually pre-activate Windows? The fact that they _can_ does not imply that they _do_. So, in practice, the actual answer to my question may be "Yes, Windows will remain unactivated"? For example, the HP document that I have linked in the post seems to imply that they _do not_ pre-activate Windows.

Comment: @lyricallywicked I'm usure how you've come to that conclusion after my detailed comments. I don't know if all OEMs do, but Dell has in the past, so if you have questions about a specific OEM, please contact that OEM and ask, as **it depends on how the OEM configured their ZTI Task Sequence.**. OEMs don't make their ZTI Task Sequence public _(most don't even know what a ZTI Task Sequence is)_; even then, the Task Sequence is model specific. A _ZTI_ and _ZTI Task Sequence_ are not the same things - a ZTI uses only an answer file, whereas a ZTI Task Sequence is a Deployment Share.

Comment: @JW0914 So SLP 3.0 requires the OEM not only to individualize every machine but also to connect it to the internet after imaging the OS? Because prior to that the SLP worked offline and online activation was considered impracticable for a manufacturing process.

Comment: @JW0914 because afaik KMS activation still works without internet as long as there is a KMS server on the LAN. Is there a similar solution for OEMs?

Comment: @xenoson _(Please don't multi-post comments unless exceeding the character count;, instead, please edit the previous one, or copy/paste into a new one, deleting the old)_. Please read my comments and the man pages in [this](https://superuser.com/a/1721319/529800) answer, as I've explained enough of ZTI Task Sequences for folks to do their own research and answer their own questions. The CoA OEMs are required to provide customers is not a "recovery" product key, it's just a product key since customers purchase Windows with a new PC - there's information about this on Microsoft Docs as well.

Comment: @JW0914 Sorry for the multiple comments. It was more of a brainstorm and I will eventually put that info into the answer. Your ZTI answer is great. But the key to to this question is the deferred activation state. OEMs would never approve a process that involved touching every OS on every machine. They will just image a master for sake of simplicity. With recovery I mean the factory recovery image on disk.

Comment: @xenoson As previously mentioned, OEMs deploy Windows to PCs via Deployment Share Task Sequences, with a different Task Sequence per model _(possibly per model configuration - depends on how they inject/install the OEM drivers for all components)_. No imaging occurs - the default `install.wim` is loaded into MEM and the Deployment Share with ZTI Task Sequences is configured; once done, MEM creates a WinPE `boot.wim` with all data for the Task Sequence, which is then copied into a boot partition on a blank HDD; upon the first boot of the system, WinPE boots and the Task Sequence auto starts.

Comment: @xenoson: the current version of the answer starts with a quote, but there is no link to the source of the quote (i.e. another answer). Can you please add this link?

Comment: @xenoson: regarding the 'Deferred Activation' state, it looks like something that _may be_ enabled by a particular vendor, i.e. not necessarily enabled by all vendors. I have not found any document claiming that this approach is applied to all PCs with pre-installed Windows 10. For example, neither ASUS nor Dell documents that I have linked in the updated post do not mention anything about the possibility of 'Deferred Activation'. Moreover, this third state, technically, is _not_ the 'Activated' state.

Comment: @JW0914: I am given two statements of yours: 1. "OEMs can pre-activate Windows via their ZTI [Zero Touch Install] Task Sequence"; 2. "most [OEMs] don't even know what a ZTI Task Sequence is". Doesn't this lead to a conclusion that most OEMs do not pre-activate Windows?

Comment: @lyricallywicked "_(most don't even know what a ZTI Task Sequence is)_" was referring to folks in general, not OEMs - unless someone has configured their own Deployment Share, or performed mass deployments of Windows in their job, it's likely ~95% of folks have no idea what a Deployment Share or ZTI Task Sequence is, as these are advanced and complex methods of deploying Windows.

Comment: @JW0914: "I don't know if all OEMs do, but Dell has in the past" — what has Dell done?

Comment: @xenoson: If the state of Deferred Activation is just "the state of a freshly installed Windows 10 that was never connected to the internet", does it imply that this state is what has been described in [this linked answer](https://superuser.com/a/498715/1008469)? If yes, it is definitely not a state of Windows that "can be used normally" (as the linked HP document says) for an arbitrarily long time (assuming that the computer never goes online).

Comment: @lyricallywicked The exact behaviour may have changed to 'more graceful'. The obvious difference is the immediate mention of 'grace time expired' with W8. W7 gave 30 days of grace time to enter the retail key and it could be rearmed 3 times. Here with 10 the rearm counter says '1001'. The other answer doesn't point out if there is a MSDM in the firmware. Being 2012 it's probably not. And that may be the point of "Firmware-embedded – never needs to be on internet connection, it can be in a deferred activation state and never watermark". This would be reminiscent in behaviour to SLIC activated.

Comment: @xenoson: > Here with 10 the rearm counter says '1001' < The seemingly large number here does not matter because, according to [this page](https://redmondmag.com/blogs/it-decision-maker/2012/08/windows-8-activation-confusion.aspx), the time window will be getting shorter. You mentioned "a clean installation from a Media Creation Tool Windows 10 21H2 ISO on offline OEM hardware" — what does "OEM hardware" mean? A computer with pre-installed Windows?

Comment: @lyricallywicked Yes, with MSDM table, otherwise it wouldn't activate online. But since you asked for fresh reinstalls I did a fresh reinstall. I can't rip apart that guys laptop and do a full reset to look at the factory default, sorry. Without MSDM W10 might go into the nagging notification mode after grace time is over.

Comment: @xenoson: "But since you asked for fresh reinstalls I did a fresh reinstall." — I admitted the possibility of a "clean install" in my first comment to this answer, but this was not a part of my primary question. Can you please clarify: _before_ you re-installed Windows, what was the "License Status" of the _pre-installed_ OS before the first time it was connected to the internet?

Comment: @lyricallywicked Fresh install on an empty hard drive. The original OS if of course licensed but was not involved. I can not tell you what the license status of a shipped  OEM pre-installed windows is that comes straight out of the box. But all your sources say it is not activated online. Somebody with new bought hardware would have to answer that. But OOBE asks for network connection and you have to say 'I don't have internet'. Then that person could check `slmgr /dlv`. Maybe you put that on the top of your question. I'm curious too!

Comment: @lyricallywicked But I must say I would be surprised it's anything else. The error code [0xC004F034](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000129709/windows-will-not-activate-error-code-0xc004f034) on the screenshots "is occurring on systems shortly after the completion of the Out of Box Experience (OOBE)".

Answer (score -3):

No legally preinstalled Windows comes pre-activated. Bulk installations usually have a key saved and read from the BIOS, so the key from the box doesn't have to be entered AFAIR, but the last few PCs that I bought for friends still had to be activated nevertheless, though it happens more or less automatically.
Pirated copies have usually some sort of KMS preinstalled which technically simulates a server that would activate or confirm the activation of the local copy. Normally KMS is used by bigger companies that use it to manage the activation.
Technically Windows XP Pro was the last Windows version that had some sort of mechanism, where some keys were accepted without any external activation factor like internet or phone.

So yes, in my experience it will remain unactivated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137021/discussion-on-answer-by-rarog4k-what-is-the-activation-status-of-windows-10-pre).