# Windows 10 pro key installation

Tags: windows, windows-10, product-key

I have just purchased a Windows 10 pro key from ebay, and it doesn't work.

The seller states that the key will only work on a clean install of windows 10, and not as an upgrade.

I have used the windows media creation tool (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to create a bootable usb.

However it always install windows home edition, could this be the issue.

Regards

Comment: Keys are version specific.

Comment: You can set the MCT to install Pro - see https://superuser.com/questions/1020961/prevent-windows-10-installer-from-using-the-preinstalled-serial-key-without-disa

Comment: After we install and activate a product key on our PC, the hardware will connect with the product key and leave the information on server side. So if you want to change the product key, we could activate it with another product key by typing "slui.exe 4" with a phone call. Or change the product key through This PC\Properties\change product key. There is no need to install the key with a new ISO image.