# Update SLIC with Windows 10 Pro key so Windows installer uses it

Tags: windows-10-pro

I have a Dell laptop with Windows 10 Home. I have also purchased Pro key.

From my experience, if I reinstall fresh, the USB doesn't ask me for a key at all, it just grabs the license information from SLP/SLIC/whatever else it uses (UEFI install).

Then, after a reinstall, I have to "upgrade" to Pro again by entering the key. Since the Pro license had been activated on my laptop before, it goes pretty smoothly, that's not the problem.

My question is if it's possible to (somehow) update SLIC information to the upgraded Pro key, so upon a fresh install, it will install Pro instead of Home edition.

**Edit:**
As @Ramhound has explained in the comments, this may not be possible, but my intent was the opposite of the proposed possible duplicate: 
[Prevent Windows 10 installer from using the preinstalled serial key without disabling UEFI](https://superuser.com/questions/1020961/prevent-windows-10-installer-from-using-the-preinstalled-serial-key-without-disa)

Instead of preventing the installer from using the preinstalled key, what I wanted to do was update the key in SLIC so that the Windows installer uses it and installs the correct edition of Windows **without having to enter my key every single time I install it**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Windows 10 installer from using the preinstalled serial key without disabling UEFI](https://superuser.com/questions/1020961/prevent-windows-10-installer-from-using-the-preinstalled-serial-key-without-disa)

Comment: If you fix the ISO you don't have to type anything when you install Windows 10.  Which is exactly what you do now, except, it installs Windows 10 Home instead of Windows 10 Professional.  What you do currently install Windows 10 Home, then upgrade to Windows 10 Professional, which is an entire extra step.

Comment: The whole point of my question was (ideally) to use an unmodified installation media that will pick up the correct key from SLIC. That was the reason why I wanted to update SLIC so that I could use any installation media without modification. Also when I sell the laptop in the future, I don't have to supply the purchased Pro key with it. So that the new owner can reinstall windows and not worry about an upgrade to Pro... Fixing the ISO is not a problem for me. Like I said, it is still the best solution to my problem, but my original question was about updating SLIC.

Comment: No you cannot modify that part of the uefi firmware.