# Change windows pro N to pro version

Tags: windows, windows-10

I currently have windows 10 pro N. I want to install the normal windows 10 version.
To do this I tried running https://www.microsoft.com/nl-nl/software-download/windows10 the installs medium for windows 10 but it automatically install windows 10N version. Im willing to reinstall my whole os but **I do not have a cd/usb  at the moment**. Is it possible to go from windows 10 n to windows 10?

Comment: See this>>>>https://www.tenforums.com/installation-upgrade/57285-upgrade-pro-n-version-full-pro.html

Comment: @Moab "In other words, your only option is to clean install Windows 10 PRO on the machine now running Windows 10 PRO N, completely replacing it. Kari" Thats what i tried.

Comment: That is not what the link said, please read the answer carefully, it said to download and install the Media Feature Pack from Microsoft.

Comment: @Moab I want to do a clean install, the media pack gave a lot of issues.

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart - You don’t have a license to Windows 10 Professional.  You will either have to purchase the upgrade or install the Media Pack.  You not having a license to Windows 10 Professional is evident by the fact Windows detected a key to Windows 10 Professional N

Comment: @rambound I also have a windows 10 key, I did not get the option to switch version or enter the licesnse.

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart - How you install Windows 10 Professional when a laptop comes with a different edition is well documented problem one I have answered before (several times)

Comment: You made no mention of having a Windows 10 Professional license.  You can modify the [sources\ei.cfg](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062) so you will be prompted for which version you want to install.  Once installed you can activate your Windows 10 Professional key.

Comment: Exact duplicate to this question has been answered here: [Prevent Windows 10 installer from using the preinstalled serial key without disabling UEFI](https://superuser.com/questions/1020961/prevent-windows-10-installer-from-using-the-preinstalled-serial-key-without-disa)

Comment: @Ramhound I do not have a cd/usb at the moment.

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart - Then you will be unable to do a clean install of Windows.  Which means you can simply do an in-place upgrade to Windows 10 Professional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `dism` tool to query the ISO for version indices and then install the one you want. I have done this in the past directly to a newly partitioned secondary HDD (the drive then gets deployed to a new machine) via a mounted ISO, but it can also be done during a normal clean install (I think shift+f10).

There are a number of steps, but the essential commands:

`diskpart` to `list vol`(make a note of the proper disk) `exit`

`dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:D:\Sources\install.wim` (replace `D:` with proper letter for the ISO location. `.wim` may need to be `.esd`)

This enumerates the possible indices of verisons. Note the one you have the proper key for.

`dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:D:\Sources\install.wim /index:1 /ApplyDir:G:\` (**again, check the `D:` and `G:` locations to ensure they are the correct ISO and destination partitions and update the index identifier**)

`G:\Windows\System32\bcdboot G:\Windows` to make the partition bootable.

I would strongly suggest you use these commands as a stepping stone for doing a google search for a tutorial such as: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/84331-apply-windows-image-using-dism-instead-clean-install.html