# How do I see all Windows licenses linked to my Microsoft account?

Tags: windows-10, license, microsoft-account

I had Windows 10 Home, the license for which was linked to my Microsoft account, then I bought a key to upgrade to Pro, which is now also linked to my Microsoft account.

I'd like to see the licenses linked to my account and I'd like to know how to switch between licenses.

Edit: I want to switch back to Home if possible.

Comment: I checked my Microsoft Account and I agree with the above. Windows licenses are not there. You cannot just switch back to Home. You have to reinstall Windows. Stick with Pro. It has everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I had Windows 10 Home, the license for which was linked to my Microsoft Account, then I bought a key to upgrade to Pro, which is now also linked to my Microsoft account.  I'd like to see the licenses linked to my account and I'd like to know how to switch between licenses.

Microsoft does not provide a way to view your Windows licenses linked to your Microsoft Account.  Unless you have Retail Window license keys they can't be transferred to other devices anyways.  You don't actually need to know your Windows 10 Home license key to install Windows 10 Home on your device.  **Once you install Windows 10 Home on your device it will automatically activate.**

> I want to switch back to Home if possible.

You would need to specifically install Windows 10 Home.  You can do this by specifying this edition within the appropriate file contained on the ISO.  The simplest method to accomplish this task is to modify it to list all available editions within the installation environment and you simply selection the edition you want to install.  **You will have to make the appropriate changes to `ei.cfg` and `PID.txt` both are contained within the ISO.**

Source:

- [Prevent Windows 10 installer from using the preinstalled serial key without disabling UEFI](https://superuser.com/questions/1020961/prevent-windows-10-installer-from-using-the-preinstalled-serial-key-without-disa/1020963#1020963)

Answer (score 4):

There is a link somewhere on Microsoft's site where you can see all the computers and licenses linked to your account. For instance, if you have a computer in the office and the kid's play room, you might see a list something like

<Office PC Name> - Windows 10 Pro 
<Kids PC Name> - Windows 10 Home

EDIT: I have found the page. I believe this is what the OP was looking for.
https://account.microsoft.com/devices

You probably will not be able to switch licensees back and forth, but this page will at least show you what devices and OS versions you have linked to your account.

Comment: I don't think this shows *licences*, only devices.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the https://account.microsoft.com/billing/orders?period=AllTime&type=All&filterChangeCount=1 URL, you will see entries like these

[image]

If you click "Show order details" you will see billing details (amount and shipping address) but no more. For OEM licenses tied to single PC neither the license key nor the serial number won't be showed, and these licenses doesn't appear in "Services & subscriptions" menu.

You have to blindly install Windows and add to it the MS account to check if the license works on your PC.