# Disabling telemetry in the Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC evaluation

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

I'm having trouble installing the Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC evaluation version. At the end of the installation, I am still taken through tons of dark patterns regarding consumer-level features, and am not able to disable telemetry (only the "Basic" level is offered) either.

Is this expected behavior, or is my install somehow messed up and is somehow turning into a retail version (the machine most likely had a retail version of Windows 10 installed - could it be silently picking the product key from there instead)?

Comment: Some bios's have a key embeded and will be used when installing>>>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1020961/prevent-windows-10-installer-from-using-the-preinstalled-serial-key-without-disa

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise doesn’t recognize retail or oem licenses

Comment: I am not sure why a quite accurate answer on telemetry data based on Microsoft evidence would be downvoted.  Downvote was wrong.