# ProductKey setting in autounattend.xml at Windows Setup not being read

Tags: windows-installation, xml, setup, unattended

I've been trying to use DataImage component of Windows Setup to unpack an extra WIM (aside from insall.wim) to another partition (`D:`) during windows installation. I needed an answer file, so I went to https://www.windowsafg.com/ for a template that I assumed works. I then stripped it down for what I need it to do, while leaving everything out so they would default & hopefully leave me with exactly the same installation experience.

Here's the autounattend.xml I prepared (my actual product key is censored with Xs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ImageInstall>
                <OSImage>
                    <InstallFrom>
                        <Path>sources\install.wim</Path>
                    </InstallFrom>
                    <InstallTo>
                        <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                        <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
                    </InstallTo>
                    <InstallToAvailablePartition>false</InstallToAvailablePartition>
                    <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
                </OSImage>
                <DataImage wcm:action="add">
                    <InstallFrom>
                        <Path>sources\d.wim</Path>
                    </InstallFrom>
                    <InstallTo>
                        <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                        <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                    </InstallTo>
                    <Order>1</Order>
                </DataImage>
            </ImageInstall>
            <UserData>
                <ProductKey>
                    <Key>XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX</Key>
                </ProductKey>
            </UserData>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ProductKey>XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX</ProductKey>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>
```

Yet, when I leave this autounattend.xml at the root of the installation media & then boot to it, the setup early on says it cannot read the ProductKey tag. What's wrong with my answer file?

Comment: Have you tried to use [PID.txt](https://superuser.com/questions/1020961/prevent-windows-10-installer-from-using-the-preinstalled-serial-key-without-disa) instead?