# Can I install Windows 11 Pro from Windows 11 Home PC without a USB?

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade, windows-sandbox

My laptop comes with Windows 11 Home and now I want to use Windows 11 Pro because I need Windows Sandbox. The upgrade costs $110 so I don't intend to go that route. I don't mind the "Activate Windows" sticker so I intend to just install it without any license key.

Now the problem is, somehow I cannot find any USB drive for now. I know you could install it directly from ISO file but after detection, the Setup would only allow me to install Windows 11 Home (no option to choose another edition). I don't mind a Clean install.

[image]

Is there anyway I can install Windows 11 Pro from my Windows 11 Home?

Comment: You shouldn't need to install or reinstall, just apply a Windows 11 Pro licence key.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/upgrade-windows-home-to-windows-pro-ef34d520-e73f-3198-c525-d1a218cc2818 it should be as simple as going to **Start > Settings > System > Activation** and then select **Change product key**

Comment: As for the reason you cannot choose any other edition, the installer is detecting your embedded key, you can avoid that by modifying the ISO to indicate it's a retail installation allowing you to choose any edition of Windows.  [I have given you everything you need to resolve this yourself, I am NOT going to submit an answer, since you indicated you will be running Windows without a license.](https://superuser.com/questions/1020961/prevent-windows-10-installer-from-using-the-preinstalled-serial-key-without-disa/1020963#1020963). It also is essentially a duplicate of an exist question.

Comment: @Mokubai thanks, I am aware I can upgrade using Product Key. Problem is, I won't be buying it so there is no product key, nor can I upgrade it from Windows Store.

Comment: You can use the [Windows 11 Professional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/kms-client-activation-keys) KMS license key to install and/or upgrade to Windows 11 Professional or use PID.txt to install Windows 11 Professional.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried the KMS method but it didn't work (error trying to apply the key I got from that page). I used your PID method, it is showing up as installing Windows 11 Pro now! That's awesome

Comment: I am confused, the KMS method I suggested, can only be acomplished by using the PID.txt file.

Comment: @Ramhound Ah... I tried running `slmgr /ipk`, thinking it would change my Windows to the pro version (even with invalid key). I edited the ISO file with that key and it works. Thanks :)

Comment: `slmgr /ipk` woulld have only worked, if you installed Windows with the KMS key, that would have activated your installation. Alternatively, if you changed your license to a legitimate Professional license key, your installation would have been upgrade to Professional.